# How can I write the following octave code without a for loop?

Tags: matlab, octave

For the following octave code snippet:

```
stepTerm = zeros(3,1);
for i = 1:3
  stepTerm(i,1) = some97ElementRowVector * some97by3Matrix(:,i);
end
```

Is it possible to write the above code without the for loop?

Comment: Please create a MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve It's not obvious what size stepTerm has before you enter the loop or perhaps it wasn't even initialized/allocated (Don't append in a loop if you know the final size)

Comment: I'm surprised this code works. No variable names are allowed to start with numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's wrong with

```
stepTerm = (97ElementRowVector * 97by3Matrix).';
```

?

on MATLAB,

```
clc
N = 1e6;    
a = rand(1,97);
B = rand(97,3);

tic
for ii = 1:N
    stepTerm0 = sum(bsxfun(@times, a.', B)).'; 
end
toc

tic
for ii = 1:N
    stepTerm1 = (a*B).';
end
toc

max(abs(stepTerm0 - stepTerm1))
```

Gives

```
Elapsed time is 12.114381 seconds.
Elapsed time is  1.827436 seconds.
ans =
    2.4869e-014
```

Answer (score 4):

This is possible using [**`bsxfun`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [**`sum`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) as follows:

```
stepTerm = sum(bsxfun(@times, 97ElementRowVector , 97by3Matrix.'),2)
```

or

```
stepTerm = sum(bsxfun(@times, 97ElementRowVector.' , 97by3Matrix)).'
```

Comment: `sum/bsxfun/times` to perform what is essentially matrix multiplication is slower than actually performing matrix multiplication itself (also evidenced by @Rody's timing tests).  However, this is a good thing to look at if you wanted to implement this by yourself without MATLAB.  It shows the right steps from beginning to end.

Comment:  totally agreed with that @rayryeng 